# How to prevent css for one specific item in an <ul>?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a website using Twitter Bootstrap, in which I now want to display a LinkedIn login button for which I'm trying to use [Bootstrap Social](http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/), a small css file ([sources here](https://github.com/lipis/bootstrap-social/blob/gh-pages/bootstrap-social.css)). When I use the simple code below on a regular part of the website, I'm getting a perfectly fine button.

```
<a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-linkedin">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> Sign in with LinkedIn
</a>
```

[image]

But when I use it in the unordered list which makes up the menu items in the navbar I get a horrible mess:

```
<ul id="navbar" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a id="index" href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a id="faq" href="/faq">FAQ</a></li>
    <li>
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-linkedin">
            <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> Sign in with LinkedIn
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

I can of course take the button outside the `<ul>`, but then it gets displayed below the other menu items.

Does anybody know how I can display the linkedin button next to the menu items while maintaining its proper styling? Or is there any other easy solution to this? All tips are welcome!

Comment: It would seem to me that your other CSS is messing it up, not just putting it in the `<ul>` tag

Answer (score 0):

your LinkedIn button seems to be grabbing properties from your nav, navbar-nav, navbar-right.

you need to make the properties on the LinkedIn button !important or setup specific styling to override the other twitter bootstrap css

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the default css for the navbar elements by defining a class for its parent `li`:

```
<li class="my-linkedin">
        <a class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-linkedin">
            <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> Sign in with LinkedIn
        </a>
    </li>
```

for example:

```
li.my-linkedin a {
color:white;
}
```